# Rails 'activemodel' and 'activerecord' namespaces in repository?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, internationalization, locale

im trying to set a custom locale (i18n) to a new Rails app..
Could someone tell me where i can accomplish with the following?
Where i can find these **'namespaces' to be removed**? => *'activemodel' and 'activerecord' namespaces are removed from Rails repository*

```
# remove these aliases after 'activemodel' and 'activerecord' namespaces are removed from Rails repository
activemodel:
errors:
  <<: *errors
activerecord:
errors:
  <<: *errors
```

Answer (score 0):

Please go through the documentation of Rails on I18N - http://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html

This is very self-explanatory and will help you to understand.

For `errors`:

```
es:
  activerecord:
    errors: "errores"
```

Good luck.

Comment: Already checked the documentation.. but, still cannot find where are these "namespaces" located...

Comment: I am sorry, but not able to understand whatever you want to convey with `namespaces to be removed` thing. Can you please tell, what is your exact requirement?

Comment: Hello, thanks in advance for your help... im trying to setup a locale 'es.yml' following all the steps mentioned in rails-i18n @gitHub.. the translations are working OK, the only one is giving problems is the plural form of the word 'error' => 'errors'...

Comment: INCORRECT: Este formulario contiene 2 errors - CORRECT: Este formulario contiene 2 errores..

Comment: Maybe the problem is related with this '# remove these aliases after 'activemodel' and 'activerecord' namespaces are removed from Rails repository'.. but i dont know how to remove these namespaces..

Comment: Checking on server? Tried restarting it?

Comment: Yes sir.. this is frustrating..!